# Kali & NOOBS in pi

Tags: boot, operating-systems, noobs, berryboot, kali

I have read many tutorials and guides, that try to explain how to have two OSes Kali and Raspbian (Wheezy) in the Pi using Berryboot. The problem is that I do not know how, where and when to install Berryboot, this is after or before installing NOOBS or Kali.

I tried two ways to achieve this.

**First I copied NOOBS in the pi first**. After pluging it to a display, mouse and keyboard and connecting it to the power supply, it asks if I want to install (i) NOOBS in the pi and that would erase the whole content of the sd card.

At this moment I understood that NOOBS itself does not allow to create partitions on first boot.

(in another instance)

**Second I tried to install Kali first**, because I thought it probably allow me to create partitions once installed in the Pi in the case Kali have not used the whole sd card storage. Unfortunately it does.

I hope you understand me, I tried my best English!

PS: I do not care if you suggest me not to use Berryboot, the main problem is dual-booting Kali and NOOBS. And it is not needed to answer all here, a useful webpage link would be really appreciated.

Comment: why do you want a dualboot-system with this two systems? because Kali is also based on Debian like Raspbian!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy In that sense, there's no point dual booting *any* two GNU/Linux systems.   They all have access to the same software and the only major differences are the package manager and the init system.   But some people may prefer to do this so they can have two different configurations without too much fuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain it in a short and easy way:

You are thinking wrong... NOOBS is not an OS but something like a bootloader! - so you can either use NOOBS or BerryBoot.

I would advise you to use BerryBoot as explained on the [Homepage](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot)!

First install Raspbian with the built-in installer and then use "BerryBoot menu editor" - "Add OS" to install Kali via the [right image](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/) from a flash drive.

Comment: I guess that this is the answer I was looking for. I recognize it now, I missunderstood what Berryboot and NOOBS were exactly. Thanks

Comment: Note that "flash drive" mentioned above pertains to choosing the option & sub-option Add OS -> Copy OS from USB Stick at this time.

Answer (score -1):

Kali is made for raspberry as it is arm based program but it can harm your sdcard... i have faced many problems, like corruption of software of kali and it boots up on tty1/tty2 on recovery mode.... i have to manually connect keyboard to it and execute "fsck" command to repair... i don't like to connect it to hdmi and keyboard....